# Jacobian in Hamiltonian dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

I was trying to show that for an infinitesimal time evolution in classical Hamiltonian dynamics preserves volume by showing that the following Jacobian 
$$
\left|\frac{\partial(q(t),p(t))}{\partial(q(t_{0}),p(t_{0}))}\right| = +1
$$
By expanding $q(t)$, $p(t)$ as,
$$
q(t)=q(t_{0})+\dot{q(t)}\Big|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2)
$$ 
$$
p(t)=p(t_{0})+\dot{p(t)}\Big|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2)
$$
using Hamilton's equation we could say 
$$
q(t)=q(t_{0})+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\Bigg|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2)
$$ 
$$p(t)=p(t_{0})-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\Bigg|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2)
$$ 
From the definition of jacobian matrix I get the following matrix $$\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1+\partial_{q}\partial_{p}H|_{t_{0}}\delta t+O(\delta t^2) & \partial^2 _{p}H|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2)\\ -\partial^2 _{q}H|_{t_{0}} \delta t+O(\delta t^2) & 1-\partial_{p}\partial_{q}H|_{t_{0}}\delta t + O(\delta t^2) \end{array}\right|$$ Is there any other way of intuitively understanding this?

Comment: The determinant is $O(\delta t^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view of your expansion, the temporal derivative of the Jacobian determinant, if evaluated **exactly** at $t=t_0$, is
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial t}|_{t_0} =\lim_{\delta t \to 0 }\frac{J(t_0+ \delta t) - J(t_0)}{\delta t}= \lim_{\delta t \to 0 }\frac{\left(1 + O(\delta t^2)\right)-1}{\delta t} =0$$
*where I used Schwarz' theorem on second derivatives in computing the determinant of the Jacobian matrix you expanded, so that terms of order $\delta t$ cancel* (I am assuming that the Hamiltonian function is $C^2$).
Next, observe that $$J(t) = J(t_0) J(t-t_0)$$
and also
$$J(t+\delta t) = J(t_0+ \delta t) J(t-t_0),$$
 so that, the derivative at a generic value of time $t$ is
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial t} =\lim_{\delta t \to 0 }\frac{J(t_0+ \delta t) - J(t_0)}{\delta t} J(t-t_0) =
\frac{\partial J}{\partial t}|_{t_0}J(t-t_0)= 0 J(t-t_0)=0.$$ Therefore, *$J$ is constant in time for fixed canonical coordinates.* As for $t=t_0$, again due to your expansion,   $J(t_0)= 1$, $J(t)$ takes that value  everywhere and for all times.